# How to search recursively in Dolphin File Manager?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.10, search, dolphin

**Please, do you know how to search recursively using the Dolphin file manager?**

Clicking the search option "**From Here**" is not searching recursively at all. Is there an option to allow recursive searching?

**System Information:**

- **OS Version:** Kubuntu 16.10
- **OS Type:** 64-bit
- **KDE Plasma Version:** 5.8.4
- **KDE Frameworks Version:** 5.28.0
- **QT Version:** 5.6.1
- **Kernel Version:** 4.8.0-32-generic
- **Dolphin Version:** 4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1

Comment: I have posted a bug report at this link:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=374318